# Automatic conversion of JSON form parameter in Spring MVC 4.0

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to build a Spring MVC controller which will receive a POSTed form with a parameter in JSON format, and have Spring automatically convert it to a Java object.

- Request content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- The name of the parameter that contains a JSON string is `data.json`

This is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/formHandler", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleSubscription(
        @RequestParam("data.json") MyMessage msg) {
        logger.debug("id: " + msg.getId());
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

And this is what the MyMessage object looks like:

```
public class MyMessage {
    private String id;
    // Getter/setter omitted for brevity
}
```

Perhaps not surprisingly, posting a form with parameter data.json={"id":"Hello"} results in HTTP error 500 with this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:
    Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'MyMessage' 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [MyMessage]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

If I read the [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) correctly, Jackson JSON conversion is triggered by Content-Type `application/json`, which I obviously cannot use since this is a form POST (and I don't control the POSTing part).

Is it possible to get Spring to convert the JSON string into an instance of MyMessage, or should I just give up, read it as a String and perform the conversion myself?

Comment: _and I don't control the POSTing part_ Your Client should follow the Server spec, not the other way around.

Comment: The client is a third party webhook mechanism that I have no control over. But your statement makes me curious, is there something in the HTTP spec that prohibits sending JSON data using a form field/post parameter?

Comment: No, there isn't, but with REST it's become conventional to have it in the body.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spring invokes your `@RequestMapping` methods with reflection. To resolve each argument it's going to pass to the invocation, it uses implementations of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. For `@RequestParam` annotated parameters, it uses `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`. This implementation binds a request parameter to a single object, typically a `String` or some `Number` type.

However, your use case is a little more rare. You rarely receive `json` as a request parameter, **which is why I think you should re-think your design**, but if you have no other choice, you need to register a custom `PropertyEditor` that will take care of converting the request parameter's `json` value into your custom type.

Registration is simple in an `@InitBinder` annotated method in your `@Controller` class

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(MyMessage.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        Object value;
        @Override
        public Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            value = new Gson().fromJson((String) text, MyMessage.class);
        }
    });
}
```

In this particular case, we don't need all the methods of the `PropertyEditor` interface, so we can use `PropertyEditorSupport` which is a helpful default implementation of `PropertyEditor`. We simply implement the two methods we care about using whichever flavor of JSON parser we want. I used `Gson` because it was available.

When Spring sees that it has a request parameter that you requested, it will check the parameter type, find the type `MyMessage` and look for a registered `PropertyEditor` for that type. It will find it because we registered it and it it will then use it to convert the value.

You might need to implement other methods of `PropertyEditor` depending on what you do next.

**My recommendation is to never send JSON as a request parameter. Set your request content type to `application/json` and send the `json` as the body of the request. Then use `@RequestBody` to parse it.**

Comment: "My recommendation is to never send JSON as a request parameter". I agree, but I am not controlling the sending side, I am just implementing a receiver for a third party webhook.

Comment: Is it for Mandrill? I'm guessing they had a client who could only receive form parameters instead of content body.

Comment: @NickSpacek No, it is a mechanism to receive [Unbounce webhook](http://support.unbounce.com/entries/307685-how-does-the-form-webhook-work) calls.

Comment: You don't always have control over the browser code, for example ExtJS data store widgets send JSON encoded strings as request parameters to support filtering, so you do need something like this solution on the server side.

Comment: FWIW - Slack does a similar thing with the action callbacks, basically the body is: `payload=<url-encoded, jsonified string>`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `@RequestPart` like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/issues", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
public String uploadIssue(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("issue") MyMessage issue)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `@RequestPart` annotation cannot be used with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.